# How can I get Heroku's PostgreSQL SSL Client Configuration Files?

Tags: postgresql, ssl-certificate, looker-studio, heroku-postgres

I want to connect my PostgreSQL database to Data Studio and it requires the PostgreSQL SSL Client Configuration Files:

- Server certificate
- Client certificate
- Client private

I haven't been able to find them on Heroku's platform so far.

I would appreciate it if someone could help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

These PKI components are not available unless you're using `private` or `shield` tier databases. If you are, you can likely have Data Studio make use of Mutual TLS to connect to your postgres instance. Documentation for that is [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-via-mtls)